# Problems with Decimalformat

Tags: java, formatting, decimalformat

Hey i am using the following code to format my numbers to have two decimal places

```
public String format(double num)
{
    String temp="";
    DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("R.##");
    temp=temp+df.format(num);
    return temp;
}
```

When I print out the results it gives me the answeres with only one decimal place. 
Please can someone help me stop that.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You use `#` in `DecimalFormat` which is the character that says "print the digit. if it is 0 leave it out."

You need to use `0` where 0 is also printed as 0.

E.g.

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("R.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(123.12331312);

System.out.print(bd.setScale(2,1));
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Use following way to format

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",num);
```