# Getting a double with .00

Tags: java, double

I have a `String` value; and i need to have it always with 2 decimals as a `Double` type; so, if i get `500`, i need to convert it to `500.00` being always a double value.

My problem is when i have something like`xxx.00` or `xxx.x0`, the parseDouble method removes the second 0.

My code is something like this

```
String number = "500.00";
Double numberToSave = (Double.ParseDouble(number));
```

And `numberToSave` returns `500.0`

Any ideas of how can i resolve this? I need to show the second decimal even if it is `0`.

Thank you.

Comment: You're confusing the **formatting** of the value with its actual value.

Comment: 500, 500.0, and 500.00 are all the same number. The issue isn't with `Double.ParseDouble`. You should be worrying about how to properly format the number when displaying the value to users, not storing it.

Comment: See this lik: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236335/problems-with-decimalformat/17236468#17236468

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Double` doesn't have any concept of maintaining insignificant digits.

The problem isn't the `Double` (or `double`) value you're using - it's how you then convert it *back* into a string. You should use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) which specifies the appropriate number of decimal places.

Also note that you're currently using `Double.parseDouble` which returns a `double`, but you're assigning it to a `Double` variable, which will box the value - potentially unnecessarily.

Sample code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "500.00";
        double number = Double.parseDouble(text);

        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        String formatted = format.format(number);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

Note that the above code will give you two decimal digits even if there are *more* digits available.

Additionally, if exact decimal digits matter to you, you might want to consider using `BigDecimal` instead of `double`. This is particularly important if your values actually represent currency. You should understand the difference between a floating *binary* point type (such as `double`) and a floating *decimal* point type (such as `BigDecimal`) and choose appropriately between them.

Comment: Sorry Jon. It was a mistake. I added the java docs link in your answer and removed it too.

Comment: Thank you, it was useful, you were absoluteli right, the problem was not the Double itself, it was the logic i was using.
So i have modified the code adding a String var that gets the number and format it so i can show it as i need.

Answer (score 2):

There's always [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) as well,

```
String.format("%.2f", d)
```

If you're only worried about printing the formatted value, you can use `System.out.printf`,

```
double d = 500;
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d);  // %n is a line-break
```

```
500.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `DecimalFormat` class.

Something like this `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");`.

Have a look at the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: Where by "something like" you mean "not actually #.## as the pattern"? (That would just give 500 for the sample value.)

Comment: Yeah. I thought I'd let the questioner think a little. ;)

Comment: But there's a difference between that and writing something that simply does not do what the question asks for.

Comment: arshajii - Can you help me understand what does "Something like this" means. I thought it means "a hint". Do you want questioners to be spoon fed?

Comment: Thanks Junaid, i have read about the format and the #; it helped me to learn a little more.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class, it can be used to format a doubles like this:

```
import java.text.*;

public class FormatDoubleTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double d1 = 500.00;
        double d2 = 500.001;
        double d3 = 500.009;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        System.out.println(df.format(d1));
        System.out.println(df.format(d2));
        System.out.println(df.format(d3));

    }
}
```

Comment: "#.##" isn't what's desired - that would give "500" for the original sample value.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yeah, my bad. Updated with runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NumberFormat` object.

```
String number = "500.00";
Double numberToSave = (Double.ParseDouble(number));
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
System.out.println(nf.format(numberToSave));
```